# Pulsing buttons HTML, jQuery, jQueryUI

Tags: jquery-ui, uianimation

I have successfully gotten this to work, but I have many buttons on the site that I want to pulse, and currently I am doing this with id's but I would like to move to something more flexible and use a class to select which buttons should pulse. Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SnareChops/AC6Vb/1/)

The problem I am seeing, at least in my browser (Google Chrome 25.0 on a MAC) is that the buttons pulse in as expected, but the pulse out is slow, then the next pulse in takes a couple seconds to trigger, then it takes even longer for the next change, it seems to be getting bogged down by something. Here are the animation scripts:

```
function pulseIn() {
    $(".pulse").animate({
        backgroundColor: "rgba(144,238,144,0.5)"
    }, 1000, 'swing', function () {
        pulseOut();
    });
}

function pulseOut() {
    $(".pulse").animate({
        backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)"
    }, 1000, 'swing', function () {
        pulseIn();
    });
}

pulseIn();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've [updated your code](http://jsfiddle.net/AC6Vb/2/) for you. This should pass a specific control around to pulse in and pulse out. In your code, once the first control had finished pulsing in, you executed `pulseOut` which selected all `.pulse` including the second one, even if it hadn't finished running its `pulseIn` (a bit confusing to explain but hopefully you get the gist).

```
$('.pulse').each(function(){
    pulseIn($(this));
});

function pulseIn(control) {
    control.animate({
        backgroundColor: "rgba(144,238,144,0.5)"
    }, 1000, 'swing', function () {
        pulseOut(control);
    });
}

function pulseOut(control) {
    control.animate({
        backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)"
    }, 1000, 'swing', function () {
        pulseIn(control);
    });
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much, never thought of doing that

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small snippet that can be used without using jQuery UI - only jQuery.

```
function fadeBtn(el, fadeOutSpeed, fadeInSpeed){
    el.fadeOut(fadeOutSpeed, function(){
        jQuery(this).fadeIn(fadeInSpeed, function(){
            fadeBtn(el, fadeOutSpeed, fadeInSpeed);
        });
    });
}

fadeBtn(jQuery('.pulseBtn'), 750, 2500);
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f5q6kuse/